# iOS App with Cocoapods error - .xcworkspace in Xcode does not show Podfile and Pods folder is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS application which in which I have installed **cocoapods**. It has all been working fine for years.  However after a couple of recent branches and merges, I ended up with lots of errors relating to the files in **Pods**. I tried to fix everything but had an error that I was unable to fix, so I decided that the best solution would be to reinstall cocoapods.

I did this with

**pod deintegrate**

**pod install.**

However, I now have a problem where, when I open the **.xcworkspace** from my project folder, the **Pods** folder is in red and empty, and the **podfile** is not shown in the directory at all.  However, when I look at the folder on my computer, the **podfile** is there and the **Pods** folder is populated.

So my project folder on my computer contains the **.xcworkspace**, the **podfile** and the **Pods** folder but when I open the **.xcworkspace** in **Xcode**, it appears that the **podfile** and **Pods** folder are not linked to it.

The error in Xcode currently is "Module 'Firebase' not found"

I have tried all of the following again and again to the point where it is driving me crazy, but the problem still persists.

- reinstalling again and again with **pod deintegrate** followed by **pod install**
- deleted the derived data
- rebuilding in Xcode between **pod deintegrate** and **pod install**
- restarting Xcode
- **pod clean**
- **pod install --repo-update**
- **rm -rf ~/.cocoapods**
- deleting the podfile then running **pod setup** and/or **pod init**
  again before **pod install**.
- I am making sure each time that my podfile includes the pods that I
  want to be installed (editing in **Xcode**).
- I am opening the **.xcworkspace** file NOT the **.xcodeproj** file.

I am able to successfully rebuild the pod file and reinstall pods on all occasions, but whatever I have tried, when I open the .xcworkspace in Xcode I can't see the podfile and the Pods folder is empty even though these items are in the project folder.

I've searched for solutions and tried everything I can find to no avail. Please can someone point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Does the project work if you go back to an older commit/branch?

Comment: Everything was working fine on the branch I was working on a couple of days ago.  The problems started when I checked out the master branch.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be only in the master - I just checked out another branch and it was ok.  I don't know if this helps understand how to fix the problem?

Comment: When asking a question like this, it is best to submit it as a comment. You provided a (potential) solution, and a question is not a solution. Cheers :-)